# Change view-command in Emacs and AUCTeX (pdf mode)

Tags: pdf, emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search

My version of Emacs and AUCTeX[1] uses

```
TeX-evince-sync-view
```

for viewing pdf.

This command is not working for some reason. Evince is launched but Emacs freezes and I have an error

```
Couldn't find the Evince instance for file XXX
```

I don't have the time to debug it and, moreover, I don't need the `sync` feature.

So, I'm trying to view `pdf` in a old-fashioned (simple) way (without `sync`). I tried this code (which used to work several years ago):

```lisp
(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Evince")))
```

But there is no change in Emacs. (I still have the problematic command

```
TeX-evince-sync-view
```

as default command.)

I tried to do the same but with the graphical interface (`Tools>customize AUCTeX>Tex Command>TeX view>Tex-view-program-selection` selecting "just" Evince) but no change.

How can I set Evince without `sync` as the default command for viewing `pdf`?

[1]Emacs 23.4.1 and AUCTeX 11.85-1 but I have the same problem with `emacs-snapshot 24.3.50.1`.

Comment: Does it help if you change `("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")` to just `("Evince" "evince %o")`?

Comment: this is not an answer to your question, but could you try a newer emacs? <a>http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/#Obtaining</a> and install auctex from a repository instead? i've tested both 24.2 and 24.3 and have had no problems.

Comment: I have already a very up-to-date version of Emacs (24.3.50.1) (thanks to Julien Danjou and his "emacs-snapshot" Debian package (http://emacs.naquadah.org/)) and the last version (11.87) of auctex. What works for you? Did you successfuly change the viewing command in pdf mode?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no difference with ("Evince" "evince %o").

Comment: What if you use that configuration with `emacs -q`?

Comment: no change with emacs -q (but problem solve ; see down)

Comment: Did you try to use `emacs -q` and then evaluate the suggested configuration in `*scratch*`? Using `emacs -q` is a way to see if the local configuration is the reason for the problem as it disables .emacs.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes. if the op requests it, i can delete it.

Comment: @ppr i never had to customize the variable as suggested above. if i remember correctly, i specified evince in the minibuffer. both emacs were compiled from source with the emacs 23 dependencies and auctex package was installed from repo. Over at http://superuser.com/questions/253525/emacs-auctex-how-do-i-open-the-pdf-in-evince-at-the-current-cursor-position there is a similar question in which just by removing pdfsync is more than enough.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do so. My .emacs is not the problem. I guess my issue is due to some incompatibility between packages in Debian unstable.

Comment: Have you tried using a later version of AUCTeX than 11.85?

Comment: @Gonzalo - I think this is a legitimate course of action anyone having the same problem should consider.  I think we should keep this as an answer.

Comment: @CharlesStewart OK, then.

Comment: @doed no need to delete it. I'll remove my comments shortly.

Comment: See here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2013-05/msg00011.html

Comment: @QuinnCulver: Thank you. This solved the problem for me. To summarize, for those who can't be bothered clicking the above link: just make sure there are no spaces anywhere along the file's path.

Comment: Was your Emacs/AUCTeX installed from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution: to use `` `TeX-view-program-list' `` in order to define a new viewer description (which contains an Evince command without sync). This new command will override the description of Evince defined in `` `TeX-view-program-list-builtin' `` (which contains the problematic command `TeX-evince-sync-view`).

To do so :

```
M-x customize-variable <RET> TeX-view-program-list <RET>
  <INS>
    Name = Evince
    Command = evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o
```

I have no idea why this code in .emacs does not work:

```lisp
(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Via configuration, I find the following works:

```lisp
(defun my-LaTeX-mode()
  (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list '("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o"))
  (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Evince")))
  ; Other mode specific config
  )
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-mode)
```