# How to set Zathura as your pdf viewer with AUCTeX

Tags: pdf, emacs, auctex

I have been trying to set Zathura has my pdf viewer with AUCTeX in Doom Emacs. I added `(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("zathura" "zathura --page=%(outpage) %o")))` to my `~/.doom.d/config.el` but whenever I try to view my tex file, it throws up the error `Unknown "Zathura" viewer, Check the 'TeX-view-program-selection' variable`. Is there a way fix this?

Comment: `(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Zathura")))`  The corresponding SyncTeX setup is already [built into AucTeX](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/tex.el?id=c8d5756b03790d630b42dc9b179b748d2c12aed9#n1307).

Comment: Thank you @henri, it worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up forward/inverse searches with AUCTeX and Zathura](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207889/how-to-set-up-forward-inverse-searches-with-auctex-and-zathura) or [Change view-command in Emacs and AUCTeX (pdf mode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106889/change-view-command-in-emacs-and-auctex-pdf-mode)

Comment: The second one does